# Trying to make an html button on click open url in new tab

Tags: html, css

i'm trying to make button on click open URL in new tab, when i click on the html button it's just redirect me to the page without opening new tab. how can i fix it?

**Here is the code**

```
  <button target="_blank" onclick="window.location.href='https://myhearing.co.il';" class="btn-view-site">View
                website</button>
```

Comment: You should be using `<a>` instead of `<button>`. You can always style a `<a>` to look identical to a `<button>` (e.g. `appearance:`). Right now your HTML won't work for users with JavaScript disabled, or users that want to middle-click it either.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work because the target is invalid for a button.

Either use an `<a>` tag OR do `window.open()`

Here is an example with `window.open()`:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://myhearing.co.il')" class="btn-view-site">View website</button>
```